# How to Parse Razor string using Model in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have below razor string in my project as given below.

```
string razorString = "This mail is from @Model.email";
var model = new { email = "mann@gmail.com" };
```

I need to parse razorString with given model. I have seen Razor.Parse method in RazorEngine but that method is obsolete now and replaced with Engine.Razor. So how can i achieve same with new method. Please suggest.

After using  Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, model) i got below error

[image]

Comment: Where's the M and V, and C for that matter, for your MVC application? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string template = "This mail is from @Model.email";
var model = new { email = "mann@gmail.com" };

string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, model);
```

Comment: I tried using same method but it gives error. I have updated screen shot in above question as well.

Comment: He's given you something to work with; can you look at the parameter overloads for `RunCompile` and figure it out from there?

Comment: After adding additional RazorEngine.Templating namespace its working fine now

Comment: I had to add using RazorEngine.Templating; before Engine.Razor.RunCompile would work